# How use selectedIndexChanged dropdownlist in clientSide and ServerSide

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu

How use selectedIndexChanged from asp.net dropdownlist in clientSide and ServerSide?

In clientside i want call javascript funcition!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeCursor() {
    document.body.style.cursor="progress";
}
</script>

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownSubject" runat="server" DataTextField="Word" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectedChange">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

SelectedChange is a name of function in clientside!

Thanks for help!

Comment: You would use `OnSelectedIndexChanged` for a C# .NET (backend) event. Use `onchange` for a client-side (JavaScript) event.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Add your client side function name in onchange events of dropdown like below :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownSubject" runat="server" DataTextField="Word" 
      AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectedChange" 
      onchange="changeCursor()">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 17):

In HTML (.aspx)

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownSubject" runat="server" DataTextField="Word" AutoPostBack="True" 
         OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectedChange" onchange="YourChangeFun(this);">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

In javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function YourChangeFun(ddl)
      {
         alert(ddl.selectedIndex);
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First change autopostback="false" and give onchange="js function()" and remove selected index change event.