# How to get jQuery dropdown value onchange event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have added two jQuery UI Dropdown Autocomplete script. Now I want get both value onchange of second dropdown and want to store separately in variable. How it is possible?

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

**My Fiddle:** [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/YNCTY/316/)

**My JS Code:**

```
(function($) {
            $.widget("ui.combobox", {
                _create: function() {
                    var self = this,
                    select = this.element.hide(),
                    selected = select.children(":selected"),
                    value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
                    var input = this.input = $("<input>").insertAfter(select).val(value).autocomplete({
                        delay: 0,
                        minLength: 0,
                        source: function(request, response) {
                            var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
                            response(select.children("option").map(function() {
                                var text = $(this).text();
                                if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
                                    return {
                                    label: text.replace(new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"), "<strong>$1</strong>"),
                                    value: text,
                                    option: this
                                };
                            }));
                        },
                        select: function(event, ui) {
                            ui.item.option.selected = true;
                            self._trigger("selected", event, {
                                item: ui.item.option
                            });
                            select.trigger("change");
                        },
                        change: function(event, ui) {
                            if (!ui.item) {
                                var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex($(this).val()) + "$", "i"),
                                valid = false;
                                select.children("option").each(function() {
                                    if ($(this).text().match(matcher)) {
                                        this.selected = valid = true;
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                });
                                if (!valid) {
                                    // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                                    $(this).val("");
                                    select.val("");
                                    input.data("autocomplete").term = "";
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }).addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left");

                    input.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
                        return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
                    };

                    this.button = $("<button type='button'>&nbsp;</button>").attr("tabIndex", -1).attr("title", "Show All Items").insertAfter(input).button({
                        icons: {
                            primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                        },
                        text: false
                    }).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-right ui-button-icon").click(function() {
                        // close if already visible
                        if (input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) {
                            input.autocomplete("close");
                            return;
                        }

                        // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                        input.autocomplete("search", "");
                        input.focus();
                    });
                },

                destroy: function() {
                    this.input.remove();
                    this.button.remove();
                    this.element.show();
                    $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);
                }
            });
        })(jQuery);

        $(function() {
            /*start point value*/
            $("#pick").combobox({
                change: function() {
                    alert("changed");
                }
            });
            $("#toggle").click(function() {
                $("#pick").toggle();
            });
            $("#pick").change(function() {
                var start = this.value;
            });

            /*end point value*/
            $("#drop").combobox({
                change: function() {
                    alert("changed");
                }
            });
            $("#toggle").click(function() {
                $("#drop").toggle();
            });
            $("#drop").change(function() {
                var end = this.value;
            });
        });
```

**My HTML Code:**

```
<div class="ui-widget">
        <select id="pick">
            <option value="">Select one...</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>

        <select id="drop">
            <option value="">Select one...</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: It seems you have already tried to do that, but you have missed to get the second value
`$("#drop").change(function () {
        var first = $('#pick').val();
        var second = $(this).val();
        console.log(first, second);        
        
    });`  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YNCTY/317/)  Be careful with variable scoping.

Comment: Solution: refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12517292/4425004

Answer (score 281, accepted):

Try like this

```
 $("#drop").change(function () {
        var end = this.value;
        var firstDropVal = $('#pick').val();
    });
```

Answer (score 23):

If you have simple dropdown like:

```
<select name="status" id="status">
    <option value="1">Active</option>
    <option value="0">Inactive</option>
</select>
```

Then you can use this code for getting value:

```
$(function(){

 $("#status").change(function(){
     var status = this.value;
     alert(status);
   if(status=="1")
     $("#icon_class, #background_class").hide();// hide multiple sections
  });

});
```

Answer (score 15):

```
$('#drop').change(
    function() {
        var val1 = $('#pick option:selected').val();
        var val2 = $('#drop option:selected').val();

        // Do something with val1 and val2 ...
    }
);
```

Answer (score 6):

Add try this code .. Its working grt.......

```js
<body>
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['nav'])) {
   header("Location: $_POST[nav]");
 }
?>
<form id="page-changer" action="" method="post">
    <select name="nav">
        <option value="">Go to page...</option>
        <option value="http://css-tricks.com/">CSS-Tricks</option>
        <option value="http://digwp.com/">Digging Into WordPress</option>
        <option value="http://quotesondesign.com/">Quotes on Design</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" id="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {

    $("#submit").hide();

    $("#page-changer select").change(function() {
        window.location = $("#page-changer select option:selected").val();
    })

});
</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#select').change(function() {
  var val = this.value;
  // alert(val);
  if (val == 'No') {
    $('.disable-field').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('.disable-field').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to detect a change to multiple ones:

```
<select name="status" id="status">
    <option value="1">Active</option>
    <option value="0">Inactive</option>
</select>

<select name="statusStopGo" id="anotherStatus">
    <option value="2">Stop</option>
    <option value="3">Go</option>
</select>
```

Change the first line, from.

```
$('#status').change(function() {
  var val = this.value;
  // alert(val);
  if (val == 'No') {
    $('.disable-field').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('.disable-field').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

To

```
$('#status, #anotherStatus').change(function() {
  var val = this.value;
  // alert(val);
  if (val == 'No') {
    $('.disable-field').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('.disable-field').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

[CodePen example](https://codepen.io/pmiddleton/pen/PoLObwK)