# Unable to display Ajax data in table

Tags: php, html, jquery

I am having a web page with two drop down menu, Search button and a table, the table is grabbing information on load using jquery. On loading the table grabs information fine. But when I use drop down menus and search button to update this table, it does not work, How ever the information is there in response console. Here is my code

HTML Code

```
<div id="table"></div>
```

Jquery for load table

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'folder/list.php',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#table').html(data);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Error: Unable to display');
        }
    });
```

});

Jquery for search

```
$(document).on('click', '#cont-search', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var cate = $('#cat-search').val();
var city = $('#city-search').val(); //Important 

$.ajax({
        url: 'folder/list.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
                cate:cate,
                city:city,
            },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#table').html(data);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Error: Unable to display Search');
        }
    });});
```

PHP CODE

```
require_once('abc/Item.php');

$cat = $_POST['cate'];
$city = $_POST['city'];

$ser_cont = $item->search_cont($cat,$city);?><div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="myTable-item" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>S.No.</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>R No.</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>City</th>
             </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php 
            $sno = 1;
            foreach($ser_cont as $c): ?>
                <tr align="center">
                    <td><?= $sno++; ?></td>
                    <td><?= $c['cate']; ?></td>
                    <td><?= $c['registno']; ?></td>
                    <td align="left"><?= $c['name']; ?></td>
                    <td><?= $c['dist']; ?></td>
</tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Can you add the returned json to your post as well.

Comment: Have you added the curly brackets for your $(document).on('click', '#cont-search', function(event) ??? you need to add }) to the end of your code...

Comment: Yes the brackets are there

Comment: Json return is exactly the same what i am looking for. But i dont know why its not displaying in table, Can not place the Json return here

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Is this really a PHP problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved the issue as it was not a json return so I just removed

```
dataType: 'json',
```

from my code and it worked, Thanks to every one for the comments

Answer (score 0):

you can try by changing the action method to onchange

```
$(document).on('change', '#cont-search', function(event) {
// your event
}
```

Comment: the event he is calling should not work for a dropdown, onchange is the correct event for a dropdown  :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922729/how-to-get-jquery-dropdown-value-onchange-event

Comment: Please add all clarification to the answer by editing it