# ASP call javaScript from c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

In my code I have used a dropdown `onSelectedIndexChanged` event and few things happen... I want to call JavaScript after that.... I have tried using

```
dropdown.Attributes.Add("onchange", "javascript:alert('Test');");
```

the above code does not fire

and

```
dropdown.Attributes.Add("onblur", "javascript:alert('Test');");
```

this is also not useful as the dropdown is `autopostback` and it loses focus because of that

Is there any way through which I can call JavaScript function through c#?

Comment: It should work. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517227/how-use-selectedindexchanged-dropdownlist-in-clientside-and-serverside may be useful

Comment: This would call javacript as soon as the dropdown changes... I want to call javaScript after few actions are performed....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `Your question was: Is there any way through whihc I can call Javascript function through c#`

To answer that:

You can use two methods:

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "anyUniqueName", "script here", true);
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "anyUniqueName", "script here", true);
```

1st method just puts a  block, while the second one puts the  tag at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 1):

Add this (in your C# method)

```
protected void onSelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do stuff
    ...

    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Test');", true);
}
```