# Calling Javascript function from an asp dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have an asp dropdownlist with a few selections and when I select a certain item from the list I want a javascript modal to open up. I have successfully been able to open the modal by using an html button after selecting the specific item from the drop down, but I want one less step.

Here is my code for the index changed event on the Drop down:

```
protected void ShipTo_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataListItem dli in cart.Items)
    {
        DropDownList drpShipto = (DropDownList)dli.FindControl("drpShipto");
        if (drpShipto.SelectedItem.Text == "-Add New ShipTo-")
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "function", "showDialog('newShipTo')", true);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is what I have for the js :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#newShipTo').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        draggable: true,
        title: "Add New ShipTo",
        open: function (type, data) {
            $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
        }
    });

    $('#editShipTo').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        draggable: true,
        title: "Edit ShipTo",
        open: function (type, data) {
            $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
        }
    });
});

function showDialog(id) {
    $('#' + id).dialog("open");
}

function closeDialog(id) {
    $('#' + id).dialog("close");
}
</script>
```

I know the function works, as I can swap out the call to the function to making a button visible  that with the onclick set to `showDialog('newShipTo')`

Am I just not calling it correctly using the `RegistarStartupScript`

Comment: Could you make a fiddle of this? Or otherwise show the HTML. My guess is you need to have an on change event in the HTML drop down to trigger your function.

Comment: use the onchange javascript call function handle opening your dialog based on criteria of the selected dropdown see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12517284/941398

Answer (score 2):

In your drop down, add an `onchange` event calling `showDialog('newShipTo')`.

Comment: while this works, it also calls the function on every item, not the specific item in the list. That is why I am trying to call the function from the codebehind so I can easily determine what item is being selected.

Comment: Then you need to add the logic to the showDialog function.

Hard to solve without a working fiddle. But what does console.log('type',type) and console.log('data',data) show you?

Probably something in there that you can say "if not the value I want, do nothing"

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below URL

http://dotnetgallery.com/forum/thread127-Calling-Javascript-function-from-an-asp-dropdownlist.aspx

Regards.

Comment: Link only answers are generally discouraged. Consider adding information about the solution into the answer here.

Comment: Also, where you have _//showDialog('newShipTo'); //Call your modal popup window here_ thats what this question is about, the rest of my code is working. My question is more about why `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "function", "showDialog('newShipTo')", true);` isn't working