# Control the visibility of an asp control based on the selected value of a drop down list control in ASP.NET 2.0

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I need to control the visibility of an asp Panel control based on the selected value of a drop down list control in ASP.NET 2.0 / VB.Net.  What is the best way to do this without hitting the server each time the user changes the drop down?

Basically, the drop down list has two choices.  NO or YES

If the drop down selected value is NO, I want the panel visibility set to False.
If the drop down selected value is YES, I want the panel visibility set to True.

I want the visibility to change when the value is changed.

This is an older website, and it is what it is.  I am not very familiar with what options there are for the older version.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You could achieve it with javascript or jquery if you already have it included at that website project.

Comment: I think you want to achieve this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517227/how-use-selectedindexchanged-dropdownlist-in-clientside-and-serverside

Answer (score 0):

The asp Panel control is rendered as a `<div>` in HTML, and the asp DropDownList control is rendered as a `select` in HTML. So basically, you could hide/show that div at client side (browser) with javascript (jquery if you can) detecting the change event of yout html `select` selected option and acting accordingly.

Here, an example with jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $("#yourSelectID").change(function () {
        if ( $("#yourSelectID option:selected").text() == 'yes' ) {
            $("#yourDivID").show();
        } else {
            $("#yourDivID").hide();
        };
    })
});
```

Also, to fully avoid the postback to the server, verify that your DropDownList control does not have set its AutoPostback property to true.