# How we can fire OnSelectedIndexChanged event from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

I want to fire OnSelectedIndexChanged event from client side,  when we fire that event from javascript then server side code will call.

Comment: You can call change event of javascript on dropdownlist and return true, the server side even will automatically fire.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How use selectedIndexChanged dropdownlist in clientSide and ServerSide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517227/how-use-selectedindexchanged-dropdownlist-in-clientside-and-serverside)

Comment: Do you want to fire the server event from Javascript?

Comment: Thanks for all support!!  I have used as below now its working fine   if($("<%=RadDropDownList.ClientID %>")!=null){
          var combo = $find("<%= RadDropDownList.ClientID %>");
          var itm = combo.findItemByValue(eventtype);
          itm.select();
          //$("<%=RadDropDownList.ClientID %>").trigger('onchange');
}

Answer (score 0):

Add your client side function name in onchange events of dropdown like below :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownSubject" runat="server" DataTextField="Word" 
      AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectedChange" 
      onchange="changeCursor()">
</asp:DropDownList>

<script type="text/javascript">
function changeCursor() {
    document.body.style.cursor="progress";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//declare Model in cshtml

@model yourNameSpace.YourModelName
```

// YourModelName.cs

```
public List<ClassName> ListOfObjects { get; set; }


//Controller Level

//call  YourRepository return 
//List<ClassName> RepoMethodToGetListOfObjects();

var listOfObjects = YourRepository.RepoMethodToGetListOfObjects();

//then populate model 

 model.ListOfObjects = listOfObjects

 //in your cshtml you will have 

  <td>@Html.DropDownList
  ("test",new SelectList(Model.ListOfObjects, "objectId", "Description"),
   new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "DropDownList" },
  {"onchange", "YourJavascriptFile.YourName.yourJavascriptFunctionName(this)" }})</td>

 // Javascript Function to get Value and Key back to controller

 YourName: {

             yourJavascriptFunctionName: function(sel) {
          //1way     var value = sel.value;
               var key = $("#DropDownList option:selected").text();
               var selectedDropDownValue = getDropDownValue("DropDownList");
               location.href = "/YourFolderName/YourController/SelectedDropDownValueLogic?dropdownValue=" +
                 selectedDropDownValue +
               "&dropdownKey=" +
               key;
             },  
            },

            function getDropDownValue(name) {
             return $("#" + name).val();
            }
```

// Do Some More Controller Logic when Drop Down option Selected

```
  public ActionResult SelectedDropDownValueLogic(string dropdownValue,string dropdownKey)
    {

       //Do Logic ..
          Func<AggregateClass, ModelClass> buildModel = x => new ModelClass()
              {
                 Property = x.Property,
              };

                  etc.....ForEach(x => model.ListOfObjects.Add(buildModel(x))
       //Do Logic ..
```

Comment: Adding some surrounding explanation would be nice.